# Why Python don't save csv results

Tags: python, csv

I don't understand why Python don't save results correctly, while it prints it correct. Code look like this:

```
import csv

with open("dataset_1.csv", "r") as WBI:
    data = csv.reader(WBI, delimiter = ";")
    data = list(data)

header = data[0]
data = data[1:]
WaterBandIndex = []

for row in data:
    WaterBandIndex.append(float(row[54])/float(row[83]))

print (WaterBandIndex)

with open("WBI.csv", "w+") as WBI:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(WaterBandIndex, delimiter = "|", lineterminator = "\n")
    csvwriter.writerows(WaterBandIndex)
```

Printed results are correct, but saves to csv nothing.
I'm green in programming.

Comment: You are using `WaterBandIndex` both as filename and as data? See [`csv.writer`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.writer)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `csvwriter = csv.writer(WBI,... `

Comment: `"w+"` is the wrong file mode. Use `"w"`.

Comment: I've already tested @SpghttCd advise. It returns the sequence expected error in the last line.

Comment: If you're getting an error, you should post it along with the full traceback.

Comment: '---> 21         csvwriter.writerows(WaterBandIndex)

Error: sequence expected' In that manner?

Comment: I think you could narrow where the error occurs writing the csv by first deleting eveything else, and simplifying the writing.  Try writing a csv file from a simple list of floats like `testdata= [1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0,6.0]` with one value per row.

Comment: IMO all your problem is just a typo, a copy-paste-error or sth like that. The point is: csv-writer wants as first argument the _file-object_, which is `WBI` in your case, but you gave `WaterBandIndex`, which is just a _list_ with your data... Just look at the reading part of your code, there you did it right.

Answer (score 0):

The code should work if your variable `WaterBandIndex` is not empty.

```
import csv
WaterBandIndex = ['1','2','3']

with open("WBI.csv", "w") as f:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(f , delimiter = "|", lineterminator = "\n")
    csvwriter.writerows(WaterBandIndex)
```

Comment: WaterBandIndex is not empty. I can print correct data it contains in 'print WaterBandIndex' line.

Comment: Rather if the structure of your list is the same as mine above, it should work with yours. You can test is out and let me know if it works for you.